# Unity Facebook sdk on android login permission issue

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I am currently using the facebook sdk(for unity, not the android one) in my unity project.

the login basically works.

However there are two cases, whether the android device has the facebook app installed or not.

When the user logins with the facebook app installed, all the permission shows up properly:

user_friends,publish_actions,basic_info,public_profile

However when the app is not installed, the login is done through the web player. The login

works, but when it asks for permission, only the public_profile is shown. So in the game

I'am not able to bring the user friend list.

Does anyone have this issue..?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get friend list, you have to request with graph api to get friend list something like "me?fields=id,name,friends"
Additionally, There is testing page for graph api. You can test graph api before using it what permission you gonna be needed

Check this out,
"https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895"

Comment: Hi thx, but the thing is that when the facebook app is installed, the friendlist shows up correctly, it's just when I use the web browser to log in within the app

Comment: Try graph api with facebook permission "user_friends,friends_status"